Не выполняется код, как задумано, выдает некорректное сообщение
#Вот собственно код
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    int x;
    std::cout << "Enter a number less than 10 or greater than 100: ";
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << "\n";
    
    `if (x >= 10)`
    {
        if (x > 100)
            std::cout << "More than 100, Thanks!\n";
        else
            `std::cout << " Yours is outside the limits of the specified values. Fix it!\n";`
    }
    else
        std::cout << "Less than 10, Thanks!\n";
    
    
    return 0;
}

Проблема заключается в том что не выполняется в полной мере условие if (x>=10),
т.е. при введении числа 10 пишет, что допустимый предел значений не соблюден, хотя оператором указано, что допускается равенство. Остальные условия выполняются.

Если x равно 10, входим в первую ветку и проверяем, больше ли x, чем 100. Понятно, что нет, так что ветка else выводит " Yours is outside the limits of the specified values. Fix it!\n". Что не так?...

Все спасибо разобрался, убрал скобки и переставил else в низ

Отладчик используй!

Удалили бы вы этот вопрос... Пользы от него никакой...

Знать бы как, но на самом деле Ваша констатация факта помогла мало, я в этом примере убрал фигурные скобки и переставил оператор Else в конец кода, и о чудо машина заработала, однако при попытке ввести другие значения, отличные от 10 выдает ошибку с указанием недопустимых пределов. Рисую код по книге, видимо в книге и опечатки

Код из книжки правильный, он совершенно верно обрабатывает условие Enter a number less than 10 or greater than 100
less than 10 означает, что неравенство строгое, и 10 не входит в диапазон допустимых значений.
